# How getchar() works when it is used as condition in while loop

Tags: c

I cant understand how the following code really works.

```
int main() {

char ch;

while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
{
    printf("test\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Lets say we give as an input "aaa". Then we get the word "test" as an output in 3 seperate lines.

Now my question is, for the first letter that we type, 'a', does the program goes inside the while loop and remembers that it has to print something when the '\n' character is entered? Does it store the characters somewhere and then traverses them and executes the body of the while loop? Im lost.

Comment: If you type `aaa<newline>` then typically `getchar()` does not return until you type the newline, so the loop does not operate until then. That is why you see `aaa` before the program's output. Until the newline is typed, the previous characters are held in an internal buffer.

Comment: Note that getchar() returns an int not a char

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, but when the while loop does operate it remembers what I typed. This is my question, how it remembers what I typed if its not directly printing the output.

Comment: What you typed is coming from an internal buffer: that is where it is remembered. When the loop runs, `getchar` fetches one character at a time from that buffer, until it finds the newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many layers between the user writing input into a terminal, and your program receiving that input.

Typically the terminal itself have a buffer, which is *flushed* and sent to the operating system when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (together with a newline from the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key itself).

The operating system will have some internal buffers where the input is stored until the application reads it.

Then in your program the [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function itself reads from `stdin` which is usually *also* buffered, and the characters returned by `getchar` are taken one by one from that `stdin` buffer.

---

And as mentioned in a comment to your question, note that `getchar` returns an `int`, which is really important if you ever want to compare what it returns against `EOF` (which is an `int` constant).

And you really *should* compare against `EOF`, otherwise you won't detect if there's an error or the user presses the "end-of-file" key sequence (<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on POSIX systems like Linux or macOS, or <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

What you see is due to the I/O **line buffering**.

The `getchar()` functions doesn't receive any input until you press the enter. This add the `\n` completing the line.

Only at this point the OS will start to feed characters to the `getchar()`, that for each input different from `\n` prints the test message.

Apparently the printout is done together after you press the enter.

You can change this behavior by modifying the buffering mode with the function `setvbuf()`. Setting the mode as **`_IONBF`** you can force the stream as unbuffered, giving back each character as it is pressed on the keyboard (or at least on an *nix system, MS is not so compliant).